# When you call a method of asynchronous tasks, the application quits

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context

I have a problem. I'm trying to create Activity cause asynchronous task and after the execution of the called method adapterCreate() class Profile.class where the adapter is created. It is necessary to transmit the context in the first parameter of the method. Here, for example if I am on the line to call a method in the class, all works well, if the transfer contex "this". And if I called from the asynchronous tasks, the application quits. I do not know what to do. I am hope for your help. Thank you!

**Profile.class**

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_application);

        new ParseTask(this).execute();

    }



public void adapterCreate(Activity context){

    String[] str1 = {"mesages1", "messages2"};
    String[] str2 = {"photo1", "photo2"};
    String[] str3 = {"name1", "name2"};

    adapter = new LazyAdapter(context, str1, str2, str3);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

}
```

**ParseTask.class**

```
public class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resultJson = "";

    Activity act;

    public ParseTask (Activity context){
        this.act = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("/friends.json");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            resultJson = buffer.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultJson;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

        new Profile().chatCreate();

    }
}
```

**LazyAdapter.class**

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] messages;
    private String[] photo;
    private String[] name;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    //public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] messages_c, String[] photo_c, String[] name_c) {
        activity = a;
        messages=messages_c;
        photo = photo_c;
        name = name_c;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return name.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null) vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

        TextView name_c = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name_c);
        TextView content_c = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.content_c);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        name_chat.setText(name[position]);
        content_chat.setText(messages[position]);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

**logcat log**

```
09-24 16:49:10.821 7969-7969/package E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at package.Profile.chatCreate(Profile.java:645)
    at package.ParseTask.onPostExecute(ParseTask.java:108)
    at package.ParseTask.onPostExecute(ParseTask.java:21)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post logcat log

Comment: Added, please see.

Comment: where is chatCreate() Method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You absolutely positively cannot do this:

```
    new Profile().chatCreate();
```

`Profile` is an `Activity`, which is an Android component. You cannot instantiate Android components yourself using `new`. Only the Android framework can instantiate Android components, because they need to have their `Context` set up before they can be used.

If you want to call a method on an `Activity`, then you need to use an instance of the `Activity` that has already been created by the Android framework.

Comment: And what do I do?

Comment: Your `AsyncTask` is created by the `Profile` class, and it passes a reference to itself in the constructor. Just cast `act` as `Profile` and call `chatCreate()`, like this: `((Profile)act).chatCreate();`.

Answer (score 0):

when you say `this` in an activity the context of the activity is sent but thats not the case with the async tasks (here `this` refers to the async task itself) so you will have to do is `yourActivity.this`.